# Why does $\sin\frac{1}{180} = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

In Spivak's Calculus I've come across the following:

$f(x)=\sin\frac1x$

$f(x)=0$ for $x=\frac{1}{180},\frac{1}{360}$ and so on, $x$ is in degrees.

Why is that so? $\sin(0)=0$ but $\frac{1}{180} \neq 0$ even though it's close.

Comment: I think you read it in the wrong way. f(1/180) = sin (1/(1/180))  = sin (180) = 0

Comment: $x=1/180 \to 1/x= 1/(1/180) =180$

Comment: @eipi10 you're right‍♂️

Comment: The equation in the title is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=\frac{1}{180}$, $\frac1x=180\ne\frac{1}{180}$. This is a zero of the sine function if we work in degrees.